# javax.servlet.ServletException: No credentials are available for this uiModule

Tags: tooltwist

when I try to call this piece of code,    `RoutingUIM.gotoNavpoint(uh, navpoint)`,
 it gives me the error `javax.servlet.ServletException: No credentials are available for this uiModule`.
 What are the possible conditions why this error occured? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your UimHelper (uh) from?

If you are calling `gotoNavpoint()` from within a request handler, or an intercept handler, it should also work just fine. The credentials can also be accessed by using `uh.getCredentials()`.